# Twitter quick reply type other than options?

Tags: user-interface, twitter, chat, chatbot, sttwitterapi

I am implementing the quick reply feature in a chatbot using Twitter. The chat displays some quick answers to some questions the bot is asking. Now, in the API reference shows that the quick option buttons need an attribute called **type** which is then set to **options**.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/quick-replies/api-reference/options

My questions is, are there any other types of quick replies other than **type:** "options"? Seems a little redundant to me if we can't change it. The reason I'm asking is, I'm wondering if there is a way to bring back the option buttons which were displayed inside of the chat under the last message like so:

[image: old quick reply buttons]

Rather than what is currently there, hidden in the hamburger menu:

[image: new twitter quick replies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the only form of quick reply that is available is the options array. Within that, you can use text and emoji for the labels, but there is no other format of button or object. Also note that the quick replies may not render in unofficial Twitter client applications.

You can request and suggest additional functionality via the [Twitter Developer Feedback channel](https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com/).